# Place another form right on the top of a control on this form

Tags: c#, windows, forms, location, controls

In a c# windows form project, I have two separate forms. One is called form A, which is a big one, with many controls on it. The second is called B, having small size. I want to relocate form B, so that it completely covers one of the specific controls inside form A. Simply enough, I could resize form B to match exactly the size of the control. But I couldn't find a way to position it properly. Any help?

Comment: One more thing: form B is not a child of form A.

Comment: Use the control's PointToScreen() method to get the required form location.

Comment: I did. not sucessful. my code is something like this:  var b = new B();  
b.Location = a.mycontrol.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);

Comment: Right.  No idea what "not sucessful" might mean.  These things are obvious only to you, we can't look over your shoulder.

Comment: Ok. How to set the location using the PointToScreen method? The Location property is coordinate relative to the parent container. I want to set the location on the screen. Something similar but in the opposite way of PointToScreen()

Comment: I found the solution:
    var x = p.X - b.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).X;  
    var y = p.Y - b.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).Y;  
    b.Location = new Point(f.Location.X + x, f.Location.Y + y);

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the *absolute* position of the child control on form A based on the position of the form (A). Then set the absolute position of Form B based on the calculated value.